# Pandas merging dataframes resulting in x and y suffixes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am creating my own dataset for a Uni project. I've used the merge function often and it always worked perfectly. This time I get x and y suffixes which I can not understand. I know pandas does this because -> *The rows in the two data frames that match on the specified columns are extracted, and joined together. If there is more than one match, all possible matches contribute one row each.* But I really don't get why. I assume it has to do with a warning I got earlier:

*A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
unique_website_user['PurchaseOnWebsite'] = [apply_website_user() for x in unique_website_user.index]*

I tried to merge the dataframes on the column 'CustomerID' where they obviously match. I really don't get the error.
Here is my code:
I first want to remove duplicate rows where the relevant columns are CustomerID and WebsiteID
Then I want to apply a function which returns true or false as a string randomly. Up to this point the resulting dataframe looks fine. The only warning I get is the one I described earlier.
And lastly I want to merge them and it results in a dataframe way larger than the original one. I really don't understand that.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import choice

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['AdID'] = np.random.randint(1,1000001, size=100000)

df['CustomerID'] = np.random.randint(1,1001, size=len(df))

df["Datetime"] = choice(pd.date_range('2015-01-01', '2020-12-31'), len(df))


def check_weekday(date):

    res = len(pd.bdate_range(date, date))

    if res == 0:
        result = "Weekend"
    else:
        result = "Working Day"

    return result


df["Weekend"] = df["Datetime"].apply(check_weekday)

def apply_age():

    age = choice([16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36],
    p=[.00009, .00159, .02908, .06829, .09102, .10043, .10609, .10072, .09223, .08018, .06836, .05552,
    .04549,.03864, .03009, .02439, .01939, .01586, .01280, .01069, .00905])
    return age

def apply_income_class():

    income_class = choice([np.random.randint(50,501),np.random.randint(502,1001), np.random.randint(1002,1501),np.random.randint(1502,2001)],
                   p=[.442, .387, .148, .023])
    return income_class

def apply_gender():

    gender = choice(['male', 'female'], p=[.537, .463])
    return gender

unique_customers = df[['CustomerID']].drop_duplicates(keep="first")


unique_customers['Age'] = [apply_age() for x in unique_customers.index]

unique_customers['Gender'] = [apply_gender() for x in unique_customers.index]

unique_customers['Monthly Income'] = [apply_income_class() for x in unique_customers.index]

unique_customers['Spending Score'] = [np.random.randint(1,101) for x in unique_customers.index]

df = df.merge(unique_customers, on=['CustomerID'], how='left')

df['WebsiteID'] = np.random.randint(1,31, len(df))

df['OfferID'] = np.random.randint(1,2001, len(df))

df['BrandID'] = np.random.randint(1,10, len(df))


unique_offers = df[['OfferID']].drop_duplicates(keep="first")
print(len(unique_offers))


unique_offers['CategoryID'] = [np.random.randint(1,501) for x in unique_offers.index]

unique_offers['NPS'] = [np.random.randint(1, 101) for x in unique_offers.index]

df = df.merge(unique_offers, on=['OfferID'], how='left')

def apply_website_user():

    purchase = np.random.choice(['True', 'False'])
    return purchase

unique_website_user = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CustomerID', 'WebsiteID'], keep="first").copy()
unique_website_user['PurchaseOnWebsite'] = [apply_website_user() for x in unique_website_user.index]
print(unique_website_user.head())
df = df.merge(unique_website_user[['CustomerID','PurchaseOnWebsite']], on='CustomerID', how='left')

#df['PurchaseOnWebsite']= df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'WebsiteID']).apply(apply_website_user)


print(df.head)

#Erstellen der csv-Datei
#df.to_csv(r'/Users/alina/Desktop/trainingsdaten.csv', sep=',', #index=False)
```

[image: Dataframe df -> 1000000 rows x 13 columns]

[image: Dataframe unique_website_user]

[image: Resulting dataframe -> 2897120 rows x 26 columns]

Comment: Hi Alina any sample of the data frame could help better us to understand.

Comment: Hi, I uploaded a few screenshots. The first one shows the original dataframe (100000 rows x 13 col), the second one shows the resulting dataframe (with new column) and the result of the merge (2897120 rows x 26 columns)

Comment: `unique_website_user` is a deduped version of `df`. So both would share same columns (but different rows) except newly assigned `PurchaseOnWebsite`. On `merge` simply subset for the merge column and new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to paste the data, rather than provide images, so this is just guidance as I can't test it. You have a couple issues and I  don't think they are related.

1. copy or slice warning. You might be able to get rid of this two ways. One is reconfigure the line:

   ```
   unique_website_user['PurchaseOnWebsite'] = [apply_website_user() for x in unique_website_user.index]
   ```

   to the format it is suggesting. The other, more simple way that might work is to use `.copy()` on the line before it. You are dropping duplicates and then modifying it, and pandas is just warning that you are modifying a slice or view of the original. try this:

   ```
   unique_website_user = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CustomerID', 'WebsiteID'], keep="first").copy()
   ```
2. If you just want to merge back that one column and reduce number of columns, try this:

   ```
   df = df.merge(unique_website_user[['CustomerID','PurchaseOnWebsite']], on='CustomerID', how='left')
   ```
3. Another alternative to this would be to use `groupby()` and apply your True/False function in and `apply` method. Something like:

   ```
   df.groupby(['CustomerID']).apply(yourfunctionhere)
   ```

   This gets rid of creating and merging dataframes. If you post all the code actual dataframe, we can be more specific.

UPDATE:
Saw your comment that you found your own answer. Also, this is way faster than your call to the weekday function.

```
df["Weekend"] = df['Datetime'].apply(lambda x: 'Weekend' if (x.weekday() == 5 or x.weekday() == 6) else 'Working Day')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited my question and posted the whole code. It still doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Update: It worked by this:
unique_website_user = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CustomerID', 'WebsiteID'], keep="first").copy()
unique_website_user['PurchaseOnWebsite'] = [apply_website_user() for x in unique_website_user.index]
print(len(unique_website_user))
df = df.merge(unique_website_user[['CustomerID','PurchaseOnWebsite', 'WebsiteID']], on=['CustomerID','WebsiteID'], how='left')